# Is Clearing WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag now unnecessary for setting status bar in android?

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-window

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setStatusBarColor(int)

Documentation above says that we need to clear WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag to set status bar color.

But WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS is deprecated, and after some experiments I've done, I found that setting status bar color with out clearing WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS is working without any problem for my device.

so, Is Clearing WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag now unnecessary for setting status bar in android?